# ¿Cómo puedo evitar que se creen más registros en un modelo que he creado en Django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, aplicación-web

Muy buenas, estoy comenzando a aprender Django y no se como hacer que un modelo que he creado en la base de datos no permita crear más de 1 registro.

Lo que quiero hacer es que una web sea personalizable desde el administrador de django, es algo relativamente fácil y que ya lo he logrado, pero lo que quiero es que no se puedan crear más registros dentro de este modelo ya que eso ocasionaría un problema.

```
class HomeContent(models.Model):
    titleSite = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Website Title')
    title_brand = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Brand Title')
    brand_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='HomeContent', null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Brand Image')
    caption_title = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Caption Title')
    caption_paragraph = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Caption Paragraph')
    home_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='HomeContent', null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Home Image')
    hover = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    section1 = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Title Section 1')
    section2 = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Title Section 2')
    section3 = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Title Section 3')

def __str__(self):
    return 'Home Content'
```

Ese es el código de mi modelo, todo funciona perfectamente, pero me gustaría evitar que se agregarán mas registros desde el administrador.

Answer (score 1):

Para hacerlo desde el admin en especifico lo única manera que se me ocurre es atraves de un formulario personalizado y proporcionarlo al admin, y creo que no hay otra manera de hacerlo, corriganme si estoy mal.

Primero que nada debemos crear nuestro formulario personalizado, de la siguiente manera:

```
class HomeContentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = HomeContent
        fields = '__all__'

    def clean(self):
        # Si existe un registro en la db entramos al if
        if HomeContent.objects.all().exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError('No puede crear mas registros')
```

El form tiene una validacion en el método `clean()`, que evita que se creen mas registros.

Y por ultimo proporcionamos nuestro propio formulario personalizado al admin:

```
class HomeContentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...

    form = HomeContentForm
```

Y listo eso seria todo, de esta manera no se permiten crear mas registros de dicho modelo, desde el admin específicamente al momento de crear un nuevo registro, PERO si se podrá desde una parte externa al admin, por ejemplo desde la `shell`, o desde una vista `CreateView` que gestione dicho modelo.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: No es necesario crear un formulario, se puede hacer desde el mismo objeto "HomeContent", de hecho lo hice desde el mismo objeto pero el problema es que a la hora de editar no me dejaba editar tampoco dicho registro. Como quiero crear una web editable esto debe permitirse. Así que se me ocurrió otra cosa, la cual fue deshabilitar los botones de agregar y eliminar y listo:D.

Comment: De igual forma, aprecio mucho tu respuesta. Gracias por tomarte el tiempo para tratar de ayudarme.

Comment: Desconocía totalmente sobre la posibilidad de desabilitar los botones del admin, algo muy interesante. Y un gusto poder ayudarte!

Answer (score 1):

Ya q estas tratando de hacer algo generico, puedes crear modelos opcionales donde relacionarias la cantidad permisible de cada modelo, ejemlpo:

```
class Cantidad_x_objeto(models.Model):
    objeto = ForeingKey(objeto)
    cantidad = IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['objeto', 'cantidad']
class HomeContent(models.Model):
    ....
    campos
    ....
    def clean(self):
        if not Cantidad_x_objeto.objects.filter(objeto.id=self.id).exists():
            raise ValidationError("Este modelo aun no tiene una cantidad limite establecida")
        else:
            if HomeContent.objects.count() == Cantidad_x_objeto.objects.get(objeto.id).cantidad:
                raise forms.ValidationError('No puede crear mas registros')


Claro, esto lo puedes mejorar o programar mas optimo, pero pudieras usar esta logica, asi lo puedes aplicar para cualquier modelo.
```